# Simple cluster manager for small Tensorflow distributed training?

Tags: tensorflow, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I'm just getting into distributed training with Tensorflow. At the moment, I run 4 processes on the same computer on different ports:

```
python trainer.py \
   --model models/my_model
   --model_dir model_dir/my_model \
   --train_set data/train.csv \
   --val_set data/val.csv \
   --cluster_spec '{ \
       "environment":"cloud" \
       "cluster":{ \
          "chief": ["localhost:2221"], \
          "worker":["localhost:2222"], \
          "ps":["localhost:2220"] \
       }, \
       "task":{ \
          "type":"chief", \
          "index":0 \
       }, \
     }'
```

The only thing that changes for each process is the end of the `--cluster_spec` flag where the values for `task` are specific for each role for each process.

Now I'm thinking about using the three computers I have at home instead of using just different processes within the same machine.

#### Question

Other than Kubernetes, what cluster management software could I use to simplify launching and watching those four processes across three different computers connected via WiFi? Ideally, this would be something very approachable for someone who's never done automated cluster management before.